# Warning on prepending variables with $

Tags: phpstorm

When I have a selector that I use several times, I like to prepend it with `$`  So if I'm using `$('body')` all over my script, I'll make a variable, `$body`.  The warning arises, in this particular case, when I do `$anElement.appendTo($body)`  I get the warning:

```
Argument type JQuery|jQuery|html element is not assignable to parameter type JQuery|element|string
```

I was told this is actually pretty common and acceptable practice, so is there a way I can turn this warning off?  I couldn't seem to find any particular entry that disabled this in the inspections.

What I'm doing is this:

```
$('<div>, 
    {class:"aClass", text: "some text"}
).appendTo($body);
```

Comment: Is your `$body` not a jQuery object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warning is under Javascript > General > Signature Mismatch.

Comment: The warning is there for a reason, make you understand it before you clear it. You should not clear it for your whole project

Comment: Could you elaborate on what I should do to clear it for this scenario then?  I'll add some clarity to my post.

Comment: where is `$body` defined?

Comment: here's how to disable an inspection for a single instance https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/suppressing-inspections.html#1

Comment: I'm using body as a generic example, but the `$variable` is declared in the scope where `.appendTo()` is being called.

Comment: Can I do `//noinspection` for an entire scope?  If I'm doing this multiple times in a function, I would like to succinctly apply that inspection omission to all instances of that call.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95470/discussion-between-csteele5-and-juan-mendes).